# Forms Authentication and HttpWebRequest

Tags: authentication, httpwebrequest, networkcredentials

I need to be able to login to a site via Forms Authentication using a `HttpWebRequest`.

Currently, when I provide NetworkCreditials to the request, it just redirects me to the Login page, which makes sense...but how do I go about ensuring that the request correctly authenticates without redirecting?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the site uses cookies to tracks users you need to use a [cookie container](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.cookiecontainer.aspx) in order to store the authentication cookie emitted by the server and reuse this cookie in later requests to access authenticated parts of the site.

Comment: Also you cant just use NetworkCredential. That is for transport authentication. You will have to figure out how the credentials are being passed to the page -usually through FORMS post.

Comment: Thanks @feroze, i think I'm going to have to go via the redirect,detect and post route.